# How to query elasticsearch from spring with LocalDate

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

Having this SearchQuery:

```
final SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("updateTime").gte(LocalDate.now())).build();
final List<ActivityValue> listOf = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, ActivityValue.class);
```

With Entity ActivityValue:

```
@Document(indexName = "tracking1", type = "activity")
public class ActivityValue {

@Id
private String id;

@Field(type = FieldType.Date, index = false, store = true, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate updateTime;

@Field(type = FieldType.Object, includeInParent = true)
private Vendor vendor;

@Field(type = FieldType.Object, includeInParent = true)
private QCriteria quality;

public ActivityValue() {
}

//setter and getter
}
```

If i run the query and try to receive the list i get following exception:

```
caused by: java.io.IOException: can not write type [class java.time.LocalDate]
```

The entity is stored before with the actual date as LocalDate.
I'm uncertain what is the best/easiest way to query elasticsearch and to resolve this error. Can anybody help?

Comment: Yeah, `localDate.toString()` seems to solve the above exception. @tn-nguyen should be accepted as the answer if it solved your issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
final SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("updateTime").gte(LocalDate.now().toString())).build();
final List<ActivityValue> listOf = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, ActivityValue.class);
```

I solved this problem by using `LocalDate.now().toString()` instead of `LocalDate.now()`

Comment: `.toString()` didn't work in all my cases and sometimes there was this error message: `failed to parse date field [2020-02-01T00:00] with format [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]]`. The expected format comes from an annotation at the attribute: `@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = { }, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS]")`. Using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")` instead of `.toString()` is more deterministic and works in all my cases.